# Password and username displaying in input fields?

Tags: html, browser, autocomplete

I have a silly problem that i just cant figure out. when i refresh my login page the password and username appears in the input fields. here is my code:

```
<?php include_once "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
<?php
session_start();
include_once ("includes/connect.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header('location: admin_cms.php');
}else{
    if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        if (empty($username) or empty($password)){
            $error = '<p>NOTE: Fields are blank</p>';   
        }else{
            $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ? AND user_password =?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $password);
            $query->execute();
            $num = $query->rowCount();
            if ($num == 1){
                $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                header('location: admin_cms.php');
                exit();
            }else{
                $error = "<p>NOTE: The username or password is incorrect</p>";  
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div id="login_container">
        <br><img src="images/camelhorst_logo_full.png" style="margin-top:38px;">
        <h1>LOGIN<img src="images/three_column_grid_line.png" alt="line"></h1>
        <form  acton = "admin.php" method="post" autocompleate="off">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username" required>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required>
            <input type="submit"  value="Login" name="submit_login">
        </form>
        <?php if (isset($error))
        {echo $error;}?>
      <p id="copyright_admin"> © CAMELHORSE CREATIVE STUDIO 2013 </p>
    </div><!--login_container-->

    <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can someone help me with this and also if anyone sees a issue that might be a security issue please correct me?

[image: My Login screen when i open the page or refresh]

Comment: Are you sure they're not being added by the browser?

Comment: This is likely to be the browser storing them; nothing to do with your PHP code.

Comment: this is added by your browser not by php code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

at the end of the inputs put `autocomplete="off"`

example

```
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required autocomplete="off">
```

Place Holder may also be filling it so you could remove that

```
 <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
```

You can also put the `autocomplete="off"` in the form tag

Answer (score 2):

By default, the autocomplete attribute is set to "on." Turning it off will prevent your browser from displaying other values that may have been stored. I'm pretty sure that the autocomplete attribute doesn't work inside of form tags. Inside of the input tag that you want to edit, put

```
autocomplete="off"
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp)